# Who bakes and endorses the blocks for the testnet during proposal?

Tags: governance

According to [this explanation](https://medium.com/tezos/amending-tezos-b77949d97e1e) of Tezos governance mechanism, specifically this portion of the explanation:

[image: Testing Period]

During the `Testing Period`, a test chain fork will appear in parallel to the main chain. I'm trying to conceptualize how that will actually work and the game theory behind it.

Let's say the testing period starts at block `N`, does the baker that is assigned to bake block `N` also bake testnet block `N'`?

Or will there a different baking rights assigned to testnet blocks? If so, what is the incentive for bakers/endorsers to bake the test fork, will there be a reward?

In the case where the changes to the protocol affect the proof of stake mechanism (such as the number of endorsers per block or roll sizes or number of blocks in a cycle), how would that work?

Answer (score 5):

The existing bakers bake on the testnet chain during the testing phase. What happens is that a new testnet is created and forked from the first block during the testing phase. Bakers will run both the mainnet chain as well as the testnet chain simultaneously, and baking/endorsement rights will be identical for both chains, so the effects of the protocol changes can be easily understood.

In the event that the protocol changes affect things such as roll size, I'm not certain what will happen. Inherently, baking and endorsement rights would change if the roll size changed, so I don't know exactly what will happen.